# HighTotal not showing up in /proc/meminfo

Tags: meminfo

I'm trying to evaluate what is the peak memory of a program (in a docker image).
I'm running `cat proc/meminfo` at the end but I don't see HighTotal, any idea why is that?

(using docker's debian:latest)

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        2046752 kB
MemFree:         1781060 kB
MemAvailable:    1782308 kB
Buffers:            7004 kB
Cached:           169056 kB
SwapCached:         2480 kB
Active:           116740 kB
Inactive:          93680 kB
Active(anon):      42712 kB
Inactive(anon):    43016 kB
Active(file):      74028 kB
Inactive(file):    50664 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1048572 kB
SwapFree:         898920 kB
Dirty:               124 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         32032 kB
Mapped:            38144 kB
Shmem:             51332 kB
Slab:              37356 kB
SReclaimable:      16256 kB
SUnreclaim:        21100 kB
KernelStack:        3664 kB
PageTables:         1172 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2071948 kB
Committed_AS:     743920 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       28672 kB
DirectMap2M:     2068480 kB
DirectMap1G:     3145728 kB
```

Comment: someone can explain the downvote? I have seen blog articles saying that proc/meminfo could give HighTotal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HighTotal` indicates [the total amount of high memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), and is only shown on 32-bit kernels configured with `CONFIG_HIGHMEM`.

It has nothing to do with the amount of memory used by a process. To see that, run it with `/usr/bin/time`.